# How to Send SNS Message from Lambda every 24 Hours?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I am new to Lambda and am trying to write a function that will send an email with a fluid volume through SNS every 24 hours. This Lambda function is triggered by an IoT rule, and without the 24 hour limitation, the inbox will be flooded with emails. In CloudWatch, it looks like the email is being sent even if the email_sent flag is equal to 1. So it makes me think I have not structured my parentheses and brackets correctly? Does anyone see anything wrong with this code?

```js
var email_sent = 0;  //Flag to determine if the email has been sent in the last 24 hours
var starttime = new Date();  //Date & time when the script starts running

....

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
 console.log('Start time.', starttime);
 console.log('Email Sent Flag.', email_sent);
 console.log('Received event:', event.my_volume, ' mL Volume');  //Fluid volume
 var miliseconds = new Date() - starttime;  //Calculate the time that has passed
 console.log('Miliseconds.', miliseconds);
 console.log(miliseconds/1000 + " Seconds.");
 if (miliseconds => 86,400,000) {    //Has 24 hours passed?
     email_sent = 0;   //set the email flag back to zero if the time has passed
 }
 // create/get topic
 if (email_sent == 0) {  //if the email flag is not set, setup topic and send the email
 createTopic('aws-iot-button-sns-topic', (err, topicArn) => {
     if (err) {
         return callback(err);
     }
     console.log(`Publishing to topic ${topicArn}`);
     // publish message
     const params = {
         Message: `The fluid level is low on your system: ${event.my_volume} mL.`,
         Subject: `Low Fluid Level Alert - Knight`,
         TopicArn: topicArn,
     };

     // result will go to function callback
     SNS.publish(params, callback);
     console.log('SNS Published.');
     email_sent = 1;  // after email is sent, reset the flag
     starttime = new Date();  // reset the starttime after the email is sent
 }
 );
} 
};
```

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Could you please describe your requirements in more detail? Is it "once per day, if IoT shows a value below _X_, then send a message to an Amazon SNS topic"? Would be be correct to assume that something is updating a value in IoT (perhaps a Device Shadow)? What is currently triggering the Lambda function — is IoT triggering it? Telling us more about your setup will help us provide suggestions for you.

Comment: I am measuring a fluid level in a device that is communicating to the AWS IoT Core service.  If the fluid level falls beneath a threshold, I want to send an alert using an IoT Rule that triggers a Lambda function.  Because the device shadow is updated every couple of seconds, it will flood the inbox with alerts.   So AWS support said that I need to use a Lambda function to send the email and limit its execution to once every 24 hours.  So yes, once per day, if IoT shows a value below X, then send a message to an Amazon SNS topic.

Comment: Do you actually want to send the alert every 24 hours, or would it be sufficient to send the alert only once (when the fluid level drops below the threshold)? I ask this because it might be worth publishing metrics to Amazon CloudWatch, and then using an alarm to trigger the Amazon SNS notification. If, on the other hand, you do want an alert every 24 hours, then an AWS Lambda function will need to keep track of the timing.

Comment: I only want to send an alert once the fluid level falls beneath a threshold, because it is a signal for someone to go manually refill the fluid container.   Once the fluid level falls beneath the threshold, the alerts need to be limited to once every 24 hours.   Otherwise, the inbox gets flooded with an alert every time the device shadow is updated.

Comment: Yes, but if the level drops below the threshold and one message is sent, and the level remains below the threshold, it is a requirement to send the notification again, or is that one message sufficient and there is no need to send repeated messsages? (If one message is enough, then CloudWatch could be an option. If repeated sending is required, then there would need to be additional logic and history tracking applied to the solution.)

Comment: One message could work for now.   I tried the CloudWatch option, but my problem with it is the notification content is very technical and I want to give the alert to a non-IT person.   With Lambda, I can format an email to my specifications.  To send the alert every 24 hours, I am trying to get my Lambda function to write some chronological values to DynamoDB.   Since Lamba can only live for 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved with the introduction of AWS IoT Events service.

https://aws.amazon.com/iot-events/

I created a detector model that invokes a Lambda function that sends an email through an SNS topic.

Before the introduction of this service, custom development was necessary to achieve chronological alerting through email.

Answer (score 0):

So there's a two things I see that should be done differently.

First, you have this:

`createTopic('aws-iot-button-sns-topic', (err, topicArn) => {`

Right now your function is creating needless topics without ever deleting them, this is a problem. You should instead create the SNS topic externally and reference it here by either using Lambda environment variables or hard-coding the SNS topic arn. Or, first check if a topic with that name is already existing, and don't create it if it does.

Second, Lambdas don't run for longer than [900 seconds (15 minutes)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html), so checking whether or not the script has been running for >24 hours is impossible.

What you should do instead is create a [CloudWatch event trigger that runs every 24 hours using cron](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html). This way, your lambda will run exactly one time every 24 hours (or whatever event you configure), and in the code you simply have to send the message once. There will then be no need to check what time it is or how many you already sent, since you know the event trigger happens only once, therefore your message gets sent once and your Lambda ends its execution right after.

The essence of Lambdas is they are short-lived and stateless, so design your service accordingly :)

Edit: After the comment, I understand the use case more...in this scenario, where the Lambda gets executed by IoT, I would personally store the previous execution time in SSM parameter store or DynamoDB, and then whenever the Lambda gets executed, I would get the value, check if 24 hours passed, and send the SNS if it did. You will have to do this because Lambda won't know otherwise when the last execution time was (and make sure to only update the last execution time on a successful SNS publish call, that eay you're sure that you sent a message that day)

Comment: What you are saying makes sense, Deiv.  The use case is bit more complicated though. Let me clarify. The Lambda function is only supposed to be invoked by an IoT rule if a device shadow value falls beneath a threshold.  So the rule starts the execution of the Lambda, but ultimately CloudWatch can limit its execution to once every 24 hours?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach...

- Push the temperature to **Amazon CloudWatch Metrics** (see below)
- Create an Amazon CloudWatch **alarm** to trigger when the temperature drops below a given threshold
- The alarm can send a message to an **Amazon SNS topic**
- People can subscribe to the SNS topic to **receive an email** when a message is sent

This will only send a single message when the metric drops below the threshold. There is no Lambda required (maybe).

I'm not totally sure about how to send the IoT metrics to CloudWatch (I'm not that familiar with IoT). This might be relevant: [Real-time metrics with AWS IoT Analytics and Amazon CloudWatch | The Internet of Things on AWS – Official Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/real-time-metrics-with-aws-iot-analytics-and-amazon-cloudwatch/)

Or, depending upon your system that measures the temperatures, you could just send the metrics direct to CloudWatch instead of IoT.

Here is a sample message sent by Amazon CloudWatch to Amazon SNS, which will then be sent to all subscribers of the SNS topic:

```
From: AWS Notifications <no-reply@sns.amazonaws.com>
Date: Mon, 13 May 2019 at 08:03
Subject: ALARM: "Fluid Level alert" in Asia Pacific (Sydney)

You are receiving this email because your Amazon CloudWatch Alarm "Fluid Level alert" in the Asia Pacific (Sydney) region has entered the ALARM state, because "Threshold Crossed: 1 datapoint [10.5 (12/05/19 21:58:00)] was less than or equal to the threshold (15.0)." at "Sunday 12 May, 2019 22:03:17 UTC".

View this alarm in the AWS Management Console:
https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=ap-southeast-2#s=Alarms&alarm=Fluid%20Level%20alert

Alarm Details:
- Name:                       Fluid Level alert
- Description:                Fluid level has dropped below 15
- State Change:               INSUFFICIENT_DATA -> ALARM
- Reason for State Change:    Threshold Crossed: 1 datapoint [10.5 (12/05/19 21:58:00)] was less than or equal to the threshold (15.0).
- Timestamp:                  Sunday 12 May, 2019 22:03:17 UTC

Threshold:
- The alarm is in the ALARM state when the metric is LessThanOrEqualToThreshold 15.0 for 300 seconds. 

Monitored Metric:
- MetricNamespace:                     Vat12
- MetricName:                          FluidLevel
- Dimensions:                          
- Period:                              300 seconds
- Statistic:                           Average
- Unit:                                not specified


State Change Actions:
- OK: 
- ALARM: [arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2::alertme]
- INSUFFICIENT_DATA:
```

Comment: Can you customize the CloudWatch alarm content to be more understandable to non-technical people?   Or are you suggesting that an email is generated by SNS and that is the alert that will be received?

Comment: It is not possible to customize the message sent from CloudWatch to SNS (and, therefore, to subscribers of the SNS topic). I have added a sample message above. If you wish to customize the message, you would need SNS to trigger an AWS Lambda function, which could send a custom email via Amazon Simple Email Service (SES).